# Android ClassNotFoundException DexPathList

Tags: android

> E/AndroidRuntime(4999): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class
>   "com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.SlidingTab" on path:
>   DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

I just add a custom component in my layout file, but it gives me the log.

Comment: could u post some code?

Comment: put your code and check that newly added activity is in manifiest file or not?

Comment: thanks a lot. it's all my fault!I forgot to update the resource files.I clean and rebuild the project,and it's ok

Answer (score 1):

I've just answered something like it here: [Why is my custom ButtonRenderer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838449/why-is-my-custom-buttonrenderer-not-working/48400421#48400421)

If you encounter it again this should solve it:

```
[Activity(Name = "somepackage.custombuttonrenderer")]
public class CustomButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
{ }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can delete both the build directory of your project and the build directory of your module, then sync the project and run your module again. It worked for me.